# How to stream audio from /dev/dsp?

Tags: debian, audio, http, streaming, oss

What is the best way to stream audio from `/dev/dsp` (I'm using OSS on Debian).
I would prefer HTTP streaming, but if there is a way on another protocol, I can deal with that.